# how to create woocommerce subscription for 5$ price using wordpress subscription plugin without creating the product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

how to create woocommerce subscription for 5$ price using wordpress subscription plugin without creating the product. the price can be passed to that page using shortcode
already

[woocommerce_checkout]

short code to pay one time payment. requirement is to convert one time into daily payment using woosubscription plugin.

code to make subscription using shortcode:
this is my already working code for one time payment:

```
`<!-- wp:shortcode -->
<p>[woocommerce_checkout]</p>
<!-- /wp:shortcode -->

<div class="custom-button">
 <a href="http://turntogether.itfhrm.com/donate/">Go to Donation</a>
</div>

<div class="custom-ccheckout-right-text">[xyz-ips snippet="Donate-Checkout"]</div>`
```

I want to create subscription for the same. Please tell some ideas and share code to work subscription payment

I tried the following code for subscription payment:

```
`[subscription_price price=”$1″ interval=”day” subscription_name=”Daily Subscription”]`
```

But its not working as expected.

Comment: With `”` quotes you probably can't expect anything to work properly, replace those with proper `"` or `'` first of all.

Comment: i used to add short code without ” quoutes. 

`[subscription_price price="$1" interval="day" subscription_name="Daily Subscription"]`

>>this is still not working @peter

Comment: Short answer you cant do subscription without subscription product. Any reason to not want to create product ? Read more about it here - https://woo.com/document/subscriptions/subscription-product-vs-subscription/

Comment: In our donation-based website, there is no need to create individual products. Users can make donations of variable amounts to the organization's account using the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin. To facilitate this, a dummy product can be used, and its price can be updated by users to match the amount they wish to donate.